# Unit testing angular directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a directive like this:

```
angular.module('default', []);

angular.module('default').
directive('default', function() 
{

return {
    restrict: 'A',  
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {      
      element.bind('error', function() {        
        angular.element(this).attr("src", attrs.default);

});

}

}   
});
```

I want to write unit tests for this directive.
I am using karma-jasmine for writing unit tests.
How do I go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be something like this:

```
describe('default directive', function () {
   it('Should set attribute src to value of attribute default', inject(function ($compile, $rootscope) {
      var scope = $rootscope;
      var elem = angular.element('<div default="test"></div>');
      elem = $compile(elem)(scope);
      expect(elem.children(0)[0].getAttribute('src')).toBe('test');
   }));
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. Thanks @christina. But I didn't follow the expect(elem.children(0)[0].getAttribute('src')).toBe('test');          statement

Comment: I have another directive having external html template in it.       How to go about testing such a directive?